# Does DirectAccess protect non corporate traffic on public wifi?

Tags: wifi, vpn, wpa2

If I were connected to DirectAccess over public wifi, does this provide any measure of security for non-corporate resources, such as online banking?

Would I be better served by going through corporate VPN if I had to access online banking in public?

Finally, could a university wifi network ever be considered reasonably secure even if it is on WPA2-Enterprise? (ie. is it as secure as a corporate WPA2-Enterprise at the office, or my home wifi?)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no.   DirectAccess enables split-tunneling by default, so only requests for corporate network resources will be protected by the VPN, and all other requests will be handled by the local network, so requests for things like online banking sites will only be as secure as they would otherwise be on the network you're using, as if DirectAccess wasn't connected at all.

Additionally, I don't believe that split-tunneling is an end-user configurable option with DirectAccess.  I believe it's administrator configured.  I don't see a setting for it on my machine in any case.

You final question is likely unanswerable. *Could* a university network be as secure as a corporate or home network?  Sure, why not?  They use much the same technology after all, and many home wifi networks, at least, are horribly insecure.  However, that says nothing about the security of a specific network, so is effectively useless information.

Answer (score -1):

The security of the network is proportional to the behaviours/actions/endpoints that can be executed in that context. From that definition, a public WiFi with an indeterminate number of people means on the whole it is reasonably insecure. With that in mind, most admins will compartmentalise large networks into smaller ones to reduce risk of compromise.

Comment: The question is about VPN use on public WiFi. I'm not sure how your answer addresses that. Stackexchange sites discourage answers that are not directly responding to the OP.